# Django Twilio module is not getting installed on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, twilio

I tried below 2 methods to install django_twilio module on Heroku

1) Ran 'heroku run pip install django-twilio'

2) Added 'twilio==3.6.3' to requirements.txt and start the server on heroku.

When I run 'heroku run pip freeze' I can see the twilio entry. But when I go into python and run 'import django_twilio' I get a module not found error.

Please suggest how to fix this on heroku. Same steps worked fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add the proper requirement, you only installed the `twilio` library. Your `requirements.txt` should include the following line:

```
django-twilio==0.4
```

Which will include all the other dependencies you'll need. The full `pip freeze`, after installing `django-twilio` looks like this:

```
Django==1.5.5
django-twilio==0.4
httplib2==0.8
six==1.4.1
twilio==3.6.3
unittest2==0.5.1
```

As a rule of thumb, always run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` before pushing an update to Heroku (assuming new dependencies were installed), to make sure you have a complete snapshot of your environment.